# Run different stages/templates of azure pipeline at different schedules

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a configuration file for the Azure pipeline that is scheduled through the UI to run Mon to Fri. The file has different stages and each stage calls a different template. What I want to do is run different stages/templates in different days of the week.

I tried to save different schedules through the triggers UI, but they need to be applied to the entire file.
I was also reading this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml but again, the schedule would be applied to the entire file.

Is there a way to apply a different schedule to each step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is an "out-of-box" way to do that. I think you may try to:

1. Divide your build into several and schedule them separately.

Or

2. Add a planning step that detects the day and sets an execution step variable like:

   ```
   echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=run.step1;]YES"
   ```

[Set variables in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash)

Then use it in the conditions:

```
and(succeeded(), ne(variables['run.step1'], 'YES'))
```

[Specify conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages)

Comment: Hello, thank you so much, it helped a lot.  We implemented a job to get the day of the week:  
`- stage: dayOfTheWeek
  jobs:
    - job: day
      steps:
      - powershell: |
          $day = $(Get-Date -Format dddd);
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=DayOfWeek;isOutput=true]$day"
        name: DayOfWeekJob `  

Then used this for the condition:  

 `condition: eq(stageDependencies.dayOfTheWeek.day.outputs['DayOfWeekJob.DayOfWeek'], 'Tuesday', 'Thursday')`

Comment: Sorry about formatting, can't seem to get it right here.

Comment: @user17983885 try to use `condition: in(stageDependencies.dayOfTheWeek.day.outputs['DayOfWeekJob.DayOfWeek'], 'Tuesday', 'Thursday')`